# How to create a Setup file for my Python application with password and shortcut to desktop?

Tags: python, installation

I want to create a setup file for my python application that requires user to enter a password and after installing creates a shortcut to desktop.I also would like to be able to update the application and change the password.
I tried using inno setup but after trying using it my application doesn't work.I tried using NSIS as well but i don't think it provides the user to generate a password and also a shortcut of the application for the desktop.
I'm using windows and i used pyinstaller to generate the .exe file.

Comment: this might [help](https://pbpython.com/windows-shortcut.html)

Comment: is there a non programmatic way?